# How to handle empty sheet while reading data

Tags: python, pandas

Iam reading an excel file but when one sheet is empty or sheet contains only a String like "Empty" at A1 it is throwing an exception

```
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'iterrows'
```

Below is the code I'm using

```
df = pd.read_excel(excel_file, header=None, squeeze=True, sheet_name=sheet_name)
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    if row.notnull().all():
        data = df.iloc[(i+1):].reset_index(drop=True)
        data.columns = pd.Series(list(df.iloc[i])).str.replace(' ','_')
        break

for c in data.columns:
    data[c] = pd.to_numeric(data[c], errors='ignore')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure how pythonic this is, but you could explicitly convert the `Series` to a `DataFrame` before iterating the rows:

```
df = DataFrame(pd.read_excel(excel_file, header=None, squeeze=True, sheet_name=sheet_name))
```

In the event that `read_excel` returns a `Series` the `DataFrame()` call will still return a `DataFrame`. I would also recommend adding a conditional. For example, if your `df` needs at least two columns and one row, you could use:

```
if Len(df.columns) >= 2 and len(df) >= 1:
    for i, row in df.iterrows():
        if row.notnull().all():
            data = df.iloc[(i+1):].reset_index(drop=True)
            data.columns = pd.Series(list(df.iloc[i])).str.replace(' ','_')
            break
```

This will prevent it from trying to iterate the rows (and modify the `df`) in the event that `df` is not meeting the expectation. Something like this should be built into your code before processing and returning the `df` as well, so that you reduce the risk of introducing bad data.

Answer (score 0):

if your df is empty there is no point in trying to iterate through it.

You can use `df.empty` which returns `True` or `False` to check whether the dataframe is empty before you iterate through it

Edit: usually if a sheet contains "Empty" at A1 it will still result in a pandas Series with the String "Empty" in it